# GDB issues: Can't set breakpoint on Obj-C method

Tags: tools, gdb, osx

I'm a beginner to reverse engineering, I've read through a few tutorials and know my way around some basic GDB and assembly code. After working my way through a few trivial examples I'd like to try something a bit more 'real-world'. My goal is to reverse-engineer and 'crack' Introversion Software / Ambrosia Software's game 'Uplink'.

Note that I am only doing this for the challenge, if I just wanted to play the game for free I would find a crack, not make one. The demo is freely available at http://www.ambrosiasw.com/games/uplink/.

Now, I have learned a few important things through static-analysis, using the tools Hopper and class-dump. It soon became clear that the registration-related functions lived in `ASWRegistration.framework`, but after trying some static analysis, to no avail, I decided it would be best to throw GDB at it. Loaded it up, tried to set a breakpoint on one of the interesting-looking functions.

```
(gdb) b +[ASWRegistration isRegistered:]
Function "+[ASWRegistration isRegistered:]" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) n
```

Aw, that's annoying. Let's try something else.

```
(gdb) b isRegistered
Function "isRegistered" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) n
```

Hm, maybe I'm doing something wrong...

```
(gdb) b isRegistered:
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) n
(gdb)
```

Well, that give me a different error message, it's still not working though...

Upon further examination, I've found that I can't even properly break on functions inside the executable itself.

```
(gdb) b applicationDidFinishLaunching:
[0] cancel
[1] all

Non-debugging symbols:
[2]    -[SUStatusChecker applicationDidFinishLaunching:]
[3]    -[SUUpdater applicationDidFinishLaunching:]
> 0
canceled
```

Two possible `applicationDidFinishLaunching`s, not one of them come from the actual game (I suspect they're from Sparkle.framework). It WOULD seem as though Ambrosia was smart and stripped all debugging symbols, but class-dump gives me full headers, nm gives me a bunch of symbols, and Hopper finds all sorts of methods. So I don't see why GDB can't use that. Again, I'm a beginner in all of this, maybe I'm doing something blatantly wrong. I also tried the same thing with a Mac App Store games, "Hack RUN Free", and got the same `No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command` error. Of course, the file command doesn't help at all.

Does anybody know how to fix this? I'd like to advance beyond the purely theoretical level in this ?

Comment: Have you tried `info functions` to display all function symbols within the executable ? Hopper seems to have a different (more efficient) method to extract the symbol table. It might be a GDB limit here.

Comment: Also, note that GDB can break anywhere in the executable. You just need to use one of the following: `b *0xdeadbeef` or `b *myfunction`.

Comment: Indeed, GDB doesn't find the symbols for ASWRegistration functions. Unfortunately, I don't know how to manually calculate shared library offsets. Any other debuggers for OS X that do this?

Comment: And, are you finding this symbol when trying `objdump -x` (look at the *export table*)?

Comment: @perror Not as far as I can see. The output from objdump is [here](http://pastebin.com/wuaeMS2R) if you're interested. I know it's possible to figure out the symbols, since both Hopper and a demo version of IDA seem to be able to do this. I've gotten to a point with static analysis where while I'm pretty sure I'm in the right place, my assembly skills aren't good enough that I can follow what's going on once Hopper is no longer able to find the methods for me. There are some obvious _objc_msgSend calls going on but I don't know how to find the actual code those point to.

Comment: It seems that the binutils fails to find the symbol you are looking for. And, I agree with your hypothesis, you probably went as far as it is possible with static-analysis. But, you may try [radare2](http://radare.org/y/), its debugger is different from the one of the binutils it may work better.

Comment: Have a look at [snoop-it](https://code.google.com/p/snoop-it). Requires a jailbroken iOS device, but it has a powerful analysis functionality. [Check out this guide to get started using it](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/ios-application-security-part-9-analyzing-security-of-ios-applications-using-snoop-it/). This may aid you in finding the calls you are looking for.

Comment: @Mick snoop-it looks nice, unfortunately Uplink is an OS X game, snoop-it is for iOS only.

Comment: I misunderstood. [dtrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace) can provide function tracing on OSX...it may help you here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16242756/12458

Comment: Have you tried lldb instead of gdb? lldb sometimes has information about the runtime environment that gdb doesn't.

Comment: @microtherion I have, don't remember having much success with it. I'm making good progress though, using a combination of Hopper (amazing tool!) and gdb, with break *0xaddress, info sharedlibrary for offsets, and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7275049/2091140) for finding which Obj-C method was called. I'll update back and answer my own question once the crack is done.

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C works a bit different than most languages. You have selectors in the `_ObjC` section which are used as arguments to `obj_msgSend` (which is how just about everything is invoked). There are no direct calls between functions. I suggest starting off with the Cameron Hotchkies [slides](http://dvlabs.tippingpoint.com/pub/chotchkies/Under%20the%20iHood%20-%20REcon%202008.pdf) on this topic from REcon 2008.

Comment: I understand that, the issue I was having here was that I couldn't find what what actual code was being called as a result of the `obj_msgSend` call. This was a while ago, but I believe a combination of live debugging and `otool -ov` helped me find what I was looking for.